# Calculate how many times the values are repeated inside a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is created from a select in the database, what I needed was to generate a metric from that dictionary

**Dictionary**

```
 # create database dictionary with values
 lds_data = {}
 for lds_item in db_result:
 lds_data.update ({lds_item [1]: {'code_client': lds_item [0], 'city': lds_item [2]}})
```

**Exit of the Dict:**

```
 u'BRASIL_ALIMEN ': {' code_client ': u'BRA', 'city': u'SAO PAULO '},
 u'BRASIL_CARROS ': {' code_client ': u'BRC', 'city': u'PARANA '}
```

**Example of metric:**

> **code_client:** *BRA* appears *1x* within dictionary

**Summing up:**

I need to calculate how many times the values are repeated within the **KEY** = `*code_client*`

**I tried to do it as follows:**

```
 ct = {}
 for key in lds_data:
     ct ['code_client'] = len (lds_data [key] ['code_client'])
```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: For the record, the way to show appreciation on Stack Overflow is to click the up arrow next to the thing you like. Thank-you comments tend to get deleted as noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you need to get a count of each code client in the dictionary. This code will populate the dictionary `ct` with each `code_client` as a key, and the number of occurrences as the value of each entry:

```
ct = {}
for _, value in lds_data.items():
    if value['code_client'] in ct:
        ct [value['code_client']] += 1
    else:
        ct [value['code_client']] = 1
```

EDIT: I would actually recommend using [Austin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57776445/11498682). It's effectively doing what I'm doing, but more correctly and succinctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {u'BRASIL_ALIMEN ': {' code_client ': u'BRA', 'city': u'SAO PAULO '},
 u'BRASIL_CARROS ': {' code_client ': u'BRC', 'city': u'PARANA '}}

c = Counter(v[' code_client '] for _, v in d.items())

print(c['BRA'])
# 1
```

If you print `c`, you will see that it has got counts of each value of `' code_client '`. That makes this flexible, maybe some day in future you require the count of `'BRC'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this works; how does it handle the case with

```
u'BRASIL_ALIMEN ': {' code_client ': u'BRA', 'city': u'SAO PAULO '},
u'BRASIL_CARROS ': {' code_client ': u'BRC', 'city': u'PARANA '},
u'BRASIL_OTRA   ': {' code_client ': u'BRA', 'city': u'TERRA NADA '},
```

You now have `BRA` in your code two times, but your count is not updated.

Instead, build a list of the values under `code_client` in the list of dicts, such as

```
client_list = [inner_dict['code_client'] for inner_dict in lds_data]
```

Now, make a `collections.Counter` of this list.

Can you finish from there?

Comment: I think `inner_dict` is not actually the inner dictionary, but the key of outer dictionary. So that might raise a `KeyError`.